# How to set view transitions conditionally in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Here's my scenario. I have a root view with 3 child views. In the root view I have two states:

```
@State private var currentView = "home"
@State private var priorView = "home"
```

To each child view, I pass a binding of the current and prior view, so that a button in the child can modify them. Note that the button is setting currentView to be the one we want to navigate to:

```
struct ViewB: View {
    @Binding var currentView: String
    @Binding var priorView: String

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            SettingsView()
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation {
                    self.currentView = "viewA"
                    self.priorView = "viewB"
                }
            }) {
                Text("Go Home")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

now returning to the root view, I have some conditional logic to manage what child view is currently being shown:

```
@ViewBuilder
var body: some View {
    VStack{
        if currentView == "viewA" {
            if priorView == "viewB" || priorView == currentView {
                ViewA(currentView: $currentView, priorView: $priorView)
                .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
            }
            if priorView == "viewC" {
                ViewA(currentView: $currentView, priorView: $priorView)
            }
        } else if currentView == "viewB" {
            ViewB(currentView: $currentView, priorView: $priorView)
            .transition(.move(edge: .top))
        } else if currentView == "viewC" {
            ViewC(currentView: $currentView, priorView: $priorView)
            .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
        }
    }
}
```

ViewA is the starting point and it has two buttons. One to travel to ViewB, and one for ViewB. When the user goes to ViewB, I want it to slide down as ViewA also slides down out of view. When the user goes to ViewC, I want it to slide up as View A also slides up. The effect would be as if they are positioned on a scroll like so:

ViewB

|

ViewA

|

View C

**The problem** is that when the app first loads (ie. priorView == currentView), it is impossible to know which direction the user will want to travel first, so we don't know what transition should be assigned, we don't know which direction the view should travel. So what happens with the code I have is when the user moves from the A -> B, the transitions are wrong. But if they continue to go back and forth between A & B, the transitions are perfect. Now if the user goes from A -> C, the transitions are wrong again. But if they continue to go back and forth between A & C, the animations are perfect.

**TLDR;** How do I apply transitions to a view when trigger occurs, so I have the ability to decide its direction based on some other condition?